# How to set button background programmatically with RippleDrawable (API 21)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-drawable

I subclassed `Button`. From within that class I try to change the color programmatically.

```
RippleDrawable draw = (RippleDrawable) getContext().getApplicationContext()
    .getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.raised_btn);
this.setBackground(draw);
```

Looks great so far..

[image: Default State]

But then I press the button, and it's the most random of colors. Nowhere have I specified these pinkish colors. If I set this drawable as the background via XML (`android:background="@drawable/raised_btn"`), then I have no issues. I need to set it programmatically though.

[image: Pressed State]

---

My `RippleDrawable` - `raised_btn.xml`

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:insetLeft="@dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
        android:insetTop="@dimen/button_inset_vertical_material"
        android:insetRight="@dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
        android:insetBottom="@dimen/button_inset_vertical_material">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/control_corner_material" />
            <solid android:color="@color/tan"/>
            <padding android:left="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
                android:top="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material"
                android:right="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
                android:bottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material" />
        </shape>
    </inset>
</ripple>
```

---

How do I achieve the correct ripple effect when setting the `RippleDrawable` background programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Resources` object doesn't know about the activity theme. You need to obtain the drawable from the `Context` or pass a `Theme` into `Resources.getDrawable(int,Theme)` in order for theme attributes to be resolved.

```
Context ctx = getContext();

// The simplest use case:
RippleDrawable dr1 = (RippleDrawable) ctx.getDrawable(R.drawable.raised_btn);

// Also valid:
Resources res = ctx.getResources();
RippleDrawable dr2 =
    (RippleDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.raised_btn, ctx.getTheme());

// If you're using support lib:
Drawable dr3 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.raised_btn);
```

Also, there's no reason to be using the application context here. If anything, that gives you a higher chance that the theme that you're using to resolve attributes won't match the theme that was used to inflate whatever view you're passing the drawable in to.

Comment: interesting. I thought you should always use the application context for resources. I will try this. thanks!

Comment: Passing the theme was all I needed. Thank you! `RippleDrawable draw = (RippleDrawable) getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.raised_btn, getContext().getTheme());
` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: For resources with themed colors, in particular, you should use whichever context is closest to where you're planning on placing the resource. Usually the activity context is fine, but in cases like `Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar` the action bar widget actually has a different theme with different control and text colors and therefore a different `Context`. So when you inflate a resource for an action bar icon, you should actually use the context from `ActionBar.getThemedContext()`.

Comment: How could you create everything programatically? I would like not using XML at all.